# Java Split Delimiter

Tags: java, string, split

If I want to have a delimiter which can separate by delimiter //, how can I implement it?

For example:

```
String str="i have a ball // do i /g f y"
```

I want the delimiter to be `"//"`, therefore the result will be:

```
"do i /g f y"
```

Comment: What are you delimiting? Context is helpful.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: i added a example, and sam i aleready look there and i didnt find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need the tail, as you specified in the question, then you don't need to split, but rather:

```
result = str.substring(str.indexOf("//") + 2);
```

Answer (score 11):

The string `"//"` can be used directly as a separator, it doesn't need escaping:

```
String[] data = str.split("//");
```

A different situation occurs with `"\\"`, the `'\'` character is used as escape character in a regular expression and in turn it needs to be escaped by placing another `'\'` in front of it:

```
String[] data = str.split("\\\\");
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
    String testString = "dog//cat//meow/ok";

    String[] tokens = testString.split("//");
    for(String token: tokens){
        System.out.println(token);
    }
```

Output:

```
dog
cat
meow/ok
```

Answer (score 1):

```
theString.split( "//" );
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

since the arg is a regex, it might require some escaping, but that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here No Escaping is required as the code is having string with "//" backslashes not "\" forward slashes.

**Code here works fine:**

```
String str="i have a ball // do i /g f y";
    String ss[]=str.split("//");
    System.out.println(ss[0]);
    System.out.println(ss[1]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> i have a ball
>
> do i /g f y